# MFSideMenu side menu issue

Tags: iphone

i have integrated the `MFSideMenu` in to ios app.

At the first view . i need to keep open the side bar, so i implemented

```
 [self.navigationController.sideMenu
 setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateLeftMenuOpen];
```

in to the `viewDidLoad` of that class. but there is a issue,

It has been applied to the next view. automatically the sidemenu will open.

But i have called the `[self.sideMenu setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];` to close the side menu

How can i stop this feature.??

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that MFSideMenu doesn't actually add the menus to the navigation controller until the navigation controller's `viewDidAppear` method is called.

Try putting this in your view controller's `viewDidAppear` method

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.navigationController.sideMenu setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateLeftMenuOpen];
    }];
```

Also, you can use the sideMenu's `toggleLeftSideMenu` method.

Answer (score 0):

it will work for sure

```
-(void)viewDidAppear{
[self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{}];
}
```